# Prevent @keyframe transform: rotate() from skipping its initial transform: rotate() value at the end of its animation cycle

Tags: css, keyframe

I'm trying to rotate an element 360 degrees from its starting rotation point, not from `0deg`. For example, if the starting point were `90deg` it would do a rotate from `90deg` to `90deg` (full circle).

My goal is to use a simple @keyframes animation to rotate the element instead of animating with JS. I'm currently setting the initial transform of the element through JS like this:

```
this.$element.css({
    transform: 'rotate' + startingDegreePosition + 'deg)'
});
```

The problem is that when the animation starts it only animates between its starting position and the keyframe's ending position. I was hoping that using the `1turn` value would accommodate this but it doesn't seem to work how I expected. I'd like it to be 360 degrees from its starting point instead. My feeling is that this isn't possible but I thought I'd throw this out there anyway.

Example code:

http://jsbin.com/jayedi/1/edit

You can see in the example that it will rotate from its starting point to `360deg` then cut back to its starting point again skipping the last 90 degrees . I'm looking for a smooth 360deg rotation from its starting point.

Answer (score 1):

For 90deg you need to rotate from -90deg to +90deg. I know you want to make the `90deg` dynamic and not a fixed value. In that case you have to update your `@keyframes rotate` css as well. Which is a little bit of work; you can define the keyframe css in a separate css file and read the css file content via js and modify it's content with js at runtime. Here is a jsfiddle link of how to alter @keyframe css dynamically from js:http://jsfiddle.net/russelluresti/RHhBz/3/

```css
div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: thistle;
  animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  /*     to { transform: rotateZ(1turn); } */
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateZ(90deg);
  }
}
/*///*/

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="transform: rotateZ(90deg)"></div>
</body>

</html>
```